Model evaluation approach allowing manual experimentation without data leakage
In supervised machine learning, are there any evaluation approaches beside using a fixed holdout test dataset, which allow me as a scientist to manually compare preprocessing approaches, without leaking information from the test dataset.
For example, if I want to compare feature selection approaches (e.g., recursive feature elimination vs variance threshold), if I have a fixed training/test split, I can simply manually experiment only on the training dataset to find which works best (e.g. with CV), then use that best approach in the pipeline I evaluate on the test dataset.
Cross validation or boostrapping are much more powerful evaluation approaches, but because the whole dataset may be used in testing at some point, I cannot manually test out approaches on any of the dataset without leaking information and biasing my final evaluation. Are there any smart approaches in practice that give the best of both worlds?
My context: I'm advising students on best practices for their final projects, and I'd like them to understand data leakage and its serious implications. However, I also want to encourage them to do manual comparisons between preprocessing approaches, so they have a personal sense of what strategies do and don't work for their datasets, and ideally why. However, I want them to experience the advantages of CV/bootstrapping.

Instead of splitting the data in two parts, train and test, you could split the data into more parts. Basically, every time you want to evaluate something you need data that is completely unseen.

This is often referred to as a train / validation / test split, or alternatively there is also cross-fold validation. There are many resources online which explain what proportions are recommended but it ultimately depends on how much data you have in your dataset.
